# C# Set Casing Convention Globally for Azure Function v3

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, json.net, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions and trying to convert .NET Core APIs to Azure Functions. The problem I am facing is how to globally set response naming convention (JSON). By default, it is `CamelCase` but I want to use `PascalCase`, all the solutions I found on internet were to modify the response in each function / endpoint. I would like to set it up globally

I had already added `Startup.cs` to configure DIs. Here is what I have tried in attempt to configure response JSON naming convention:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonOptions(m =>
    {
        m.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

    builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerSettings>(m =>
    {
        m.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });

    builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(m =>
    {
        m.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
        m.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

    builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(m =>
    {
        m.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
        m.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

    .....
}
```

Function Example (both return same response, which is CamelCased):

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Get))]
public async Task<IEnumerable<AppComponentViewModel>> Get([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "AppComponent/Get")] HttpRequest request)
{
    var appComponents = await _appComponentRepository.GetAll();
    return ToList(appComponents);
}

[FunctionName(nameof(Get))]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppComponentViewModel>>> Get([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "AppComponent/Get")] HttpRequest request)
{
    var appComponents = await _appComponentRepository.GetAll();
    return Ok(ToList(appComponents));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Azure function host uses 'Newtonsoft.Json' as opposed to 'System.Text,Json' introduced in .net core 3+. You can use the below code in `Startup.cs` to override MVC Json serialization behavior which would retain your property name casing same as in your entity classes. In the below code it will not convert to `camelCase` anymore, but at the same time would neither explicitly convert to `PascalCase`. It would be same as the C# object.

NOTE: Add nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` version 3.1.* ( not newest 5 at least until Function start supporting .net 5).

```cs
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddMvc()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
                {
                    o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                });
        }
```

If you want to specifically force to Pascal case for everything regardless of what is the casing in C# object, then you can create your `NamingStrategy` class to have that logic and assign it.

```cs
    public class MyNamingStrategy : NamingStrategy
    {
        protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string s)
        {
            // add logic to force name to desired casing
        }
    }
```

```cs
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddMvc()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
                {
                    o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = new MyNamingStrategy()
                    };
                });
        }
```

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json has been removed from Version 3 on. This is no longer working: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325 and will lead to following error: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14833

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the following method to setup Newtonsoft JSON configuration to stop camelCasing your properties.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
  JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() };
}
```

If you want to force everything to be PascalCasedregardless of the property casing, you'll need to roll your own resolver. See here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm