# Azure Functions 3.1 .NET Core HttpResponse changing case on serialized object

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function with an HttpTrigger. When returning an object with Pascal casing, the serialization changes the case to Camel case.

Is there a way to configure the default serialization without using a custom serialization on the response of every function?

More so, why is this happening, and how is this a feature? Changing the casing on a serialized object is a pretty big thing.

Here's a code example of the Http triggered function. When I call the method with Postman, the result is camel case, while the class is pascal.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MyService.Models;

namespace MyService.BFF
{
    public static class GetWorkOrders
    {
        [FunctionName("GetWorkOrders")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>()
            {
                new WorkOrder()
                {
                    WorkOrderId = "1",
                    CustomerId = "1",
                },
                new WorkOrder()
                {
                    WorkOrderId = "2",
                    CustomerId = "2",
                }
            };

            return new OkObjectResult(workOrders);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the language of your function app? Are you referring to the casing of your JSON response? which module/library are you using for serialization - newtonsoft / system.text ?

Comment: I've added a code example and further clarification. I'm using C#, .net core v 3.1

Comment: See if setting this property helps..https://stackoverflow.com/a/58135043/14973743

Comment: This will be apt for your Function app.., see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64894580/14973743

Comment: To be honest, I just changed my models to be camel cased. I am planning on using CosmosDb as well, and read documents can also get "camelized" when using inputBindings or triggers. I still think this is a huge bug, by changing the casing, the serialization is breaking the contract between different services.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few workarounds that you can try

1. If you want to use  `JsonSerializer`  in your own code you should pass the config to it.
   Here is a sample code -

   ```cs
   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
   {
       PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
   };
   return Json(empList, options);
   ```

   For more information, you can refer [System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyName not working for CosmosDb in .NET Core](https://www.koskila.net/system-text-json-jsonpropertyname-not-working-for-cosmosdb-in-net-core-5/)
2. You can install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson --version 3.1.1` package and include the following namespace in the startup class -  `ConfigureServices`  method. In the following code, it will no longer convert to camelCase,

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
       {
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
       });
   }
   ```

**while considering**

> I am planning on using CosmosDb as well, and read documents can also get "camelized" when using inputBindings or triggers.

CosmosDb employs camelCase rather than PascalCase, therefore these attributes will not be mapped to anything. To remedy this, add the JsonPropertyName-attribute to your CosmosDb containers to transfer the data to your C# model.

For more information, you can refer [System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyName not working for CosmosDb in .NET Core](https://www.koskila.net/system-text-json-jsonpropertyname-not-working-for-cosmosdb-in-net-core-5/)

**REFERENCES:**
[C# Set Casing Convention Globally for Azure Function v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64886727/c-sharp-set-casing-convention-globally-for-azure-function-v3/64894580#64894580)